# What does rpois() do in the following case?

Tags: r, poisson

`rpois()` takes two values (*n*, and *lambda*) to generate *n* random numbers according to Poisson distribution.

But, what is `rpois()` doing in the following case?

```
> n = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
> lamda = 10
> rpois(n, lamda)
 [1] 13 15 10  9 10 11 10 10 11 15
>
```

Answer (score 5):

from the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Poisson.html):

```
 The length of the result is determined by ‘n’ for ‘rpois’, and is
 the maximum of the lengths of the numerical arguments for the
 other functions.
```

it's therefore the same as:

```
rpois(length(n), lambda)
```

a bit more digging, it ends up calling [`do_random1` in `src/main/random.c`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/random.c#L66).  which basically says:

```
if (length(param1) == 1) {
  n = as.integer(param1)
} else {
  n = length(param1)
}
```

but in C, and with fiddling to make sure it works with "long" vectors, etc.